# Ripping CDs incredibly slow since updating to 16.04

Tags: cd-ripping

I recently updated from 14.04 to 16.04 and since then, ripping cds has been incredibly slow.  Actually, I have not tried to wait for completion of one cd rip because progress is so slow.  I have tried various cds (mfr'ed cds), and both asunder (which I used previously under 14.04 with no problems and faster write speeds--ripping a full length cd would take about 5 mins or so) and soundjuicer.  Soundjuicer tells me it is writing at speeds of ~1.5x.

Help is appreciated,

-lza

Comment: Solved my issue.  I tried ripping in Windows, and found the same problem.  I removed the optical drive, blew out any dust, and reinserted it...and voila!  Much better in Windows and Ubuntu.